# Integrating external widget in AMP

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to integrate external widget in AMP in the following way as I can't use  element in AMP:

```
<amp-script
    layout="container"
    src="https://code.jivosite.com/widget/Rs4Buc3gah"
    class="sample"
></amp-script>
```

Instead of this:

```
<script src="//code.jivosite.com/widget/Rs4Buc3gah" async></script>
```

But I don't get any results.

I can't do it with amp-iframe component, because its size is dynamic:

http://joxi.ru/a2XbB7ZU4y160r

http://joxi.ru/Dr8ZJoyTMk47J2

How to integrate external widgets in AMP in general?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830290/how-to-implement-jquery-on-amp

Comment: Post the code with a full working example and maybe I'll help you.

Comment: This is the code where I need to add external script:

https://codepen.io/miskaryan64/pen/gOrdVPp