# How to implement Jquery on AMP?

Tags: jquery, amp-html

I tried to using JQuery on AMP pages.

For example, I already fulfill the amp requirement like script/HTML amp, etc.

Here an example:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('hello-url');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('clicked');
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  document.body.appendChild(h1);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>Hello, AMPs</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/create/basic_markup/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
    <meta name="amp-script-src" content="sha384-ZvpUoO_-PpLXR1lu4jmpXWu80pZlYUAfxl5NsBMWOEPSjUn_6Z_hRTt8-pR6L4N2">
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.png"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  </head>
  <body>
    <amp-script src="js" layout="container">
        <div id="hello-url">
            Say Hello
        </div>
    </amp-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works for vanilla js, but how about implementation on Jquery, how to do it?

```
<amp-script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" layout="container">
    <div id="hello-url">
        Say Hello
    </div>
<script>
  $jquerycode with same fuction
</script>
</amp-script>
```

Comment: short answer - you can't. reason: jQuery is too large and takes too long to load. AMP sets limits for size and run-time. If you are determined to *not* rewrite target jQuery functions, you will have to prune jQuery and integrate pruned-code with target-code.

Comment: You can check for 'Actions and events' of AMP for click events actions. If you have some section of page where jQuery required you can load that section as iframe in amp with amp-iframe. inside that iframe you can load any external script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External Java Script like jQuery are [forbidden](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml/) in AMP. Except for [AMP-Iframe](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/media_iframes_3p/iframes/) or [custom Javascript](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript/).